# Problem in rendering Multiple Drilldown in fusioncharts

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, fusioncharts

I am using Django. I want use the drilldown feature in fusioncharts. I am able to get the first drilldown correctly. But when I code for the second drilldown it is showing **"No data to display"**. Also the following code renders all the charts in the same type. But I want to render the child charts in different types. I am sharing the snippet below.

```
 def chart(request):

    dataSource = {}
    dataSource['chart'] = {
        "caption": "Top 10 Most Populous Countries",
        "showValues": "0",
        "theme": "zune"
        }


    dataSource['data'] = []
    dataSource['linkeddata'] = []

    sbc = MTD.pdobjects.values('Vertical', 'Channel','Brand','Sales_Value')
    sbc_df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)#Trying to use filtered model for dataframe
    sbc_df['Sales_Value']=sbc_df['Sales_Value'].astype(float)
    chn_gb=sbc_df.groupby('Channel')['Sales_Value'].sum().reset_index()
    channel=list(chn_gb['Channel'])
    channel_val=list(chn_gb['Sales_Value'])
    sbc_gb=pandas.pivot_table(sbc_df,index=['Vertical','Channel'],values=['Sales_Value'],aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
    brd_gb=pandas.pivot_table(sbc_df,index=['Vertical','Channel','Brand'],values=['Sales_Value'],aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
    for i in range(len(channel)):
      data = {}
      data['label'] = channel[i]
      data['value'] = channel_val[i]

      data['link'] = 'newchart-json-'+ channel[i]
      dataSource['data'].append(data)


      linkData2 = {}

      linkData2['id'] = channel[i]
      linkedchart2 = {}
      linkedchart2['chart'] = {
        "caption" : "Top 10 Most Populous Cities - " + channel[i] ,
        "showValues": "0",
        "theme": "fusion",
        }

      linkedchart2['data'] = []

      sbc_filtered=sbc_gb[sbc_gb.Channel == channel[i]]
      vertical_list=list(sbc_filtered['Vertical'])
      vertical_val=list(sbc_filtered['Sales_Value'])
      for k in range(len(sbc_filtered)):
          arrDara2 = {}
          arrDara2['label'] = vertical_list[k]
          arrDara2['value'] = vertical_val[k]
          arrDara2['link'] = 'newchart-json-'+ vertical_list[k]
          linkedchart2['data'].append(arrDara2)

          linkData1 = {}
          # Inititate the linkData for cities drilldown
          linkData1['id'] = vertical_list[k]
          linkedchart1 = {}
          linkedchart1['chart'] = {
            "caption" : "Top 10 Most Populous Cities - " + vertical_list[k] ,
            "showValues": "0",
            "theme": "fusion",
            }

          linkedchart1['data'] = []

          brd_filtered=brd_gb[(brd_gb.Channel == channel[i]) & (brd_gb.Vertical== vertical_list[k])]
          brd_list=list(brd_filtered['Brand'])
          brd_val=list(brd_filtered['Sales_Value'])
          for j in range(len(brd_filtered)):
              arrDara1 = {}
              arrDara1['label'] = brd_list[j]
              arrDara1['value'] = brd_val[j]
              linkedchart1['data'].append(arrDara1)
          linkData1['linkedchart'] = linkedchart1
          dataSource['linkeddata'].append(linkData1)

      linkData2['linkedchart'] = linkedchart2
      dataSource['linkeddata'].append(linkData2)

      print(dataSource)

    column2D = FusionCharts("column2D", "ex1" , "700", "400", "chart-1", "json", dataSource)
    return render(request, 'table.html',{'output':column2D.render()})
```

Kindly help me to achieve the successive drilldown correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the chart type for the child chart you need to use configureLink API method to set the child chart type, you can also set different chart at a different level, provided the datastructure for each chart is correct, here is how you can do

```
myChart.configureLink([
    { type: 'bar2d' },
    { type: 'line' },
    { type: 'pie2d' }
]);
```

Here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/x0c2wo7k/

Please note the above sample is using plain javascript

Comment: if i add this in the html page as a script i cant get and also im getting "no data to display" in the third drill down ... help me to render the chart...

Comment: which chart type you are trying to render in the third level, please check the data structure for the chart is correct or not, else update the above fiddle and share me the link, will try to fix it

Comment: The first issue I want resolve is to render the third chart some how.(Atleast in the same type of first chart). When I click any data plot in the second chart it showing that there is ##"No data to display".##

Comment: check my above comment, please share a sample so that I can investigate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kznbap1e/                                                                             
Check this fid ... i just copy the dict(datasource) from the python code and give to fid...

Answer (score 0):

No data to display" chart message is displayed when no "category" is provided in the dataSource, or it is null.

```
{
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Top 3 Juice Flavors",
    "subcaption": "Last year",
    "xaxisName": "Flavor",
    "yaxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
    "numberPrefix": "$",
    "theme": "fusion",
    "rotateValues": "0"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Apple",
      "value": "810000",
      "link": "newchart-xml-apple"
    },
    {
      "label": "Cranberry",
      "value": "620000",
      "link": "newchart-xml-cranberry"
    },
    {
      "label": "Grapes",
      "value": "350000",
      "link": "newchart-xml-grapes"
    }
  ],
  "linkeddata": [
    {
      "id": "apple",
      "linkedchart": {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Apple Juice - Quarterly Sales",
          "subcaption": "Last year",
          "xaxisname": "Quarter",
          "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberprefix": "$",
          "theme": "fusion",
          "rotateValues": "0"
        },
        "data": [
          {
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "157000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "172000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "206000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "275000",
            "rotateValues": "0"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "cranberry",
      "linkedchart": {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Cranberry Juice - Quarterly Sales",
          "subcaption": "Last year",
          "xaxisname": "Quarter",
          "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberprefix": "$",
          "theme": "fusion",
          "rotateValues": "0"
        },
        "data": [
          {
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "102000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "142000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "187000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "189000"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "grapes",
      "linkedchart": {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Grape Juice - Quarterly Sales",
          "subcaption": "Last year",
          "xaxisname": "Quarter",
          "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberprefix": "$",
          "theme": "fusion",
          "rotateValues": "0"
        },
        "data": [
          {
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "45000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "72000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "95000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "108000"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the demo fiddle as per your requirement - https://jsfiddle.net/yxnchb50/1/

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down#chart-links-linked-charts-